# How do I work with a PowerPoint presentation using Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm getting the error shown at the bottom.

I've created a Console App targeting .NET 7.0 
I've installed the Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint package 
 
Here's the code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
Console.WriteLine("Hello from PowerPointShuffler!");
Application pptApp = new Application();
Console.WriteLine("Bye from PowerPointShuffler!");
```

The compiles without error, but with this warning:

Warning MSB3305 Processing COM reference "Microsoft.Office.Core" from path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\MSO.DLL". Type library importer encountered a property getter 'Type' on type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.SeriesGradientStopColorFormat' without a valid return type.  The importer will attempt to import this property as a method instead.

I'm using the PowerPoint that comes with a Microsoft 365 Subscription.

[image: Visual Studio error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to create a project using .Net Framework 4.8 produces no errors or warnings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Note I had to select a "Console App (.NET Framework)", not a "Console App".